# Silverlight: Determine whether DataContext is inherited or not

Tags: c#, silverlight, datacontext

At runtime in a generic fashion (i.e. iterating UIElements) can I determine if a given FrameWorkElement has a non-inherited DataContext property set?  I want a list of elements where DataContext was explicitly set, not inherited from higher up in the chain.  I thought perhaps GetBindingExpression() would help but so far it has not.  Using Silverlight beta 3.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely! Just compare the FrameworkElement Parent's DataContext using an equality operator.

It might not help in a situation where a child control has the DataContext set to the same exact item as the parent, but it would help in most scenarios.